# Proof of FONC in Nocedal and Wight's text

Tags: optimization, continuity, proof-explanation, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

In the [textbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387303030), FONC states:

[image]

With the proof:

[image]

I don't understand the following:

- Why should that condition hold simply because $\nabla f$ is
  continuous near $x^*$? I tried to apply the $\epsilon-\delta$
  definition of continuity to produce such a scalar $T > 0$, but I
  could not proceed.
- In the next line, why do we pick a new variable $\bar t \in (0, T]$? The interval $(0, T]$ seems to be quite mysterious to me. (Solved)

Comment: bullet 1: argue by contradiction. get a sequence converging to $x^*$ and then you contradict $p^T\nabla f(x^*) < 0$. 

bullet 2: You want it for $\bar{t}$ because of the last paragraph.

Comment: Could you show how you tried to resolve point 1 by applying the definition of continuity?